# Making a 9-0 synchronous down counter using flip-flops

Tags: flipflop, counter, synchronous, sequential-logic, ripple-counter

I've been trying to make a timer that starts from 0 then counts down at 9 to 0. I've been struggling to make it.  I made state tables and diagrams and for the flipflops, but when implementing to a simulator, it just doesn't give me the output I want.

I've tried making the don't cares (10-15) as 0 but still doesn't work.

Here's the state diagram:

[image]

Here's the state table:

[image]

I followed the kmap results in the simulator but still can't get it to work.

Here's my state table for the JK flip-flop:

[image]

Kmaps using Logic Friday:
[image]

Simulation in Proteus, it counts down from 0 to 9 but gets stuck at 3 and 2 going back and forth:

[image]

I got it working thank you all. A lot of misinputs was present in making the state table.

Next is to make the 2nd digit in this count down I want it to start at 6 not 0, basically 6,5,4,3,2,1,0. I made the flip-flop state table and followed the similar process I used in the first digit.

But when simulating it, it starts at 0, 7, 6, ... I want it to start at 6. How can I do this?

Comment: There is a discussion of something like this [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458311/330261). It counts up or down, though. It it looks like he did another one [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/467187/330261) that is just a down-counter, starting at 9 if I read it right.

Comment: Can you show us the 4 k-map minimizations and your final circuit solution? Also, what is 'Y' in your truth table?

Comment: @user350400 the y is an output, it serves as a clock input for the second down timer to have two digit counting down

Comment: @Noobielectrix I've added an update to my answer. I think you missed out on using the `minimize` option that is available to you in Logic Friday. Hopefully, this helps. (I'll +1 your question with this additional added work product. Thanks!)

Comment: @periblepsis hey, im trying to make this in breadboard. The outputs are correct and fine but I can't seem to drive it to the actual 7447 ic to 7 segment display it just stuck on display 0 and i have no idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### efforts noted

Your [first post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/695945) shows a lot of supplies, parts, and solderless breadboards in use. Your [second post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/696474) writes: "*I am required to use sequential circuits and combinational circuits only for this project.*" This tells me you are involved in related classwork, so not only trying to build something but also studying how to design what you may later build. This latest question now extends on the prior two, showing you are trying to acquire a specific set of useful mental tools related directly to these kinds of activities. Looks like significant effort, to me.

*(In the following, I'm borrowing table work from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/522431) to save time.*)

#### FF options

Unless homework specifically limits choices, please keep in mind there are at least these options for FFs:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Transition} & \text{JK FF} & \text{T FF} & \text{D FF}\\\hline
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
\text{start }\to\text{ end}\\\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 0\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cc}
  J & K \\\\
  0&x\\
  x&0\\
  1&x\\
  x&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
  T\\\\
  0\\
  0\\
  1\\
  1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
  D\\\\
  0\\
  1\\
  1\\
  0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The **D** column is obvious. Just present the next state you want before clocking. **T** FFs are readily made from **JK** types (just wire the J and K inputs together.) The **JK** often offers the least complicated surrounding combinatorial logic for desired state transitions. But not always. It doesn't hurt to keep all options on the table when using a simulator. Otherwise, obey physical reality (7400 family) or virtual reality (homework limits.)

#### decade down-counter starting at 0

The table I see for this problem is:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{States} & \text{FF Inputs}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}J & K & T & D\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&1&1&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}J & K & T & D\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}J & K & T & D\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}J & K & T & D\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&0&0&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    0&x&0&0\\\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cccc}J & K & T & D\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\
    1&x&1&1\\
    x&1&1&0\\\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x\\
    x&x&x&x
  \end{array} } \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The above is offered by way of comparison with your own thoughts.

I'm not going to draw out the k-maps. You can take the above table and generate those, if you like. And it's good practice. However, you can also readily plug any part of the above information into Steve Rickman's *Logic Friday* program (the latest version I have is 1.1.4.) It will minimize the logical algebra. If you do your own k-maps, verifying your findings using Logic Friday makes sense.

What I see in your question right now doesn't show your simulation efforts. So I can't be more help, yet. If you decide to include more in your question, I may then know better how to offer further details.

#### update

Now that you've added your work product, allow me to add mine for comparison, starting with the final result:

[image]

Then the Logic Friday table I prepared:

[image]

And finally the minimized output from Logic Friday:

```
Entered by truthtable:
QDJ = QD' QC' QB' QA';
QDK = QD QC' QB' QA';
QDT = QD' QC' QB' QA' + QD QC' QB' QA';
QDD = QD' QC' QB' QA' + QD QC' QB' QA;
QCJ = QD QC' QB' QA';
QCK = QD' QC QB' QA';
QCT = QD' QC QB' QA' + QD QC' QB' QA';
QCD = QD' QC QB' QA + QD' QC QB QA' + QD' QC QB QA + QD QC' QB' QA';
QBJ = QD' QC QB' QA' + QD QC' QB' QA';
QBK = QD' QC' QB QA' + QD' QC QB QA';
QBT = QD' QC' QB QA' + QD' QC QB' QA' + QD' QC QB QA' + QD QC' QB' QA';
QBD = QD' QC' QB QA + QD' QC QB' QA' + QD' QC QB QA + QD QC' QB' QA';
QAJ = 1;
QAK = 1;
QAT = 1;
QAD = QD' QC' QB' QA' + QD' QC' QB QA' + QD' QC QB' QA' + QD' QC QB QA' + QD QC' QB' QA';

Minimized:
QDJ = QC' QB' QA';
QDK = QA';
QDT = QC' QB' QA';
QDD = QD QA + QD' QC' QB' QA';
QCJ = QD QA';
QCK = QB' QA';
QCT = QD QA' + QC QB' QA';
QCD = QC QB  + QC QA + QD QA';
QBJ = QD QA' + QC QA';
QBK = QA';
QBT = QD QA' + QC QA' + QB QA';
QBD = QB QA + QD QA' + QC QB' QA';
QAJ = 1;
QAK = 1;
QAT = 1;
QAD = QA';
```

It looks to me as though you forgot to use Logic Friday's `minimize` option as shown below:

[image]

Sincerely, best wishes. It's good to see your activities!

Comment: Yeah I didn't know there's a minimize function as i just recently installed it. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Noobielectrix It's fun to see ideas like these work so well also in practice. I used these ideas (not software, as they didn't exist then) when designing my first CPU a long time back. And if I hadn't? I probably would not have succeeded in the end. And that would have probably turned me away from the path I did follow. Life changing, I guess!

Comment: Hey.. i am trying to make this now in breadboard and i seem to have a problem in my display. The outputs of the jk flip flops are correct but I can't seem to drive it on an actual 7447 ic to a 7 segment display. It is stuck on display 0. And i have no idea how to fix this. Help

Comment: @Noobielectrix I've no idea, either. Probably will need to post up a question showing what you have. If the JK FF are all showing correctly, then there is something wrong with how you are connecting up/to the 7447 or to the 7-seg display. The 7447 is designed for common-anode 7-seg displays. So make sure that's right. There's also a blanking input, etc. Disconnect everything and directly set the inputs to the 7447 by hand. Technically, you should be able to figure out the right steps on your own here. But if you stay stuck on this, write it up and ask for help I think.

Comment: I observed that i have to switch the power off in order to update the display. I tried to input a 0001 and it just outputs 0 but when i turn it off and on it updated the display to 1. Any idea?

Comment: @Noobielectrix If the only IC involved is the 7447, then the 7447 doesn't have any memory. So there's no way it can behave like that. Not that I know of. It doesn't have anything that it can latch on power-up. JK FF's on the other hand do. So if you are using them stop using them. Then test.